# How to display different login pages for general customer and wholesaler in Magento?

Tags: magento, registration

I need to keep 2 login pages at frontend for general customer group and wholesaler customer group

And admin will confirm customer as wholesaler

So how to check customer has signed up as general or wholesaler

Please advise..

Answer (score 0):

currently magento provide group for customer, so you can put dropdown of group in registration  page for user to select for which group he want to sign up and in admin you can see the group assign to user.